# Загрузка заднего фона на сайте в соответствии с расширением монитора

Tags: php, javascript, background

Как правильно реализовать загрузку заднего фона на сайте с соответствие с расширением монитора посетителя?

То есть выбрать нужное изображение для конкретного расширения.

Сайт на php.

Comment: уроки css  в помощь

Comment: Наверное все же в зависимости от размеров окна браузера?

Comment: [разные стили в зафивисомости от ширины/высоты/ориентации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Вам придется хранить эти картины в нескольких вариантов.И в зависимости от ширины браузера загружать соответствующую

Answer (score 1):

Думаю здесь помогут медиа-запросы.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://www.fullhdoboi.com/wallpapers/thumbs/6/kartinka-apelsiny-1885.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
  body {
    background-image: url("http://www.sunhome.ru/i/wallpapers/200/planeta-zemlya-kartinka.960x540.jpg");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Растягиваемый фон</title>
  <style>
   body {
    background: url(images/фон.png) no-repeat; /* Ваш фон тут */
    -moz-background-size: 100%; /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    -webkit-background-size: 100%; /* Safari 3.1+ и Chrome 4.0+ */
    -o-background-size: 100%; /* Opera 9.6+ */
    background-size: 100%; /* Современные браузеры */
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

При использовании background-size: 100% фон будет занимать всю ширину окна (не экрана)

Answer (score 0):

поправил метки, тут все таки в основном JavaScript нужен, так как php это серверная технология.

К примеру, выводите на php js объект или можно выводить как атрибут, к примеру как атрибут:

```
 <div class="bg" data-bg="для мобилки к примеру" data-bg-lg="ссылка на изображение для экранов от 1200 к примеру" data-bg-md="ссылка на изображение для экранов от 970"></div>
```

таким образом можно для любых разрешений, а затем на js обработчик, напишу с использованием jQuery, логика должна быть понятной все равно

```
$(window).on("load resize scroll",function(e){
     var width = $(window).width(),
         $blockBg = $('.bg'),
         image = $blockBg.attr('data-bg');
     if(width > 970 && width < 1200) {
         image = $blockBg.attr('data-bg-md');
     } 
     if(width > 1200) {
         image = $blockBg.attr('data-bg-lg');
     } 
     $blockBg.css('background', 'url('+image+')');
}
```

Comment: вариант Apple Vine, тож правилен, но бывает такое, что при разных разрешениях изображения должны не много меняться из-за контентной области и т.п.